# only .remove() works and not removeChildren()

Tags: javascript, removechild

So I'm trying to make a basic CRUD-like app in pure JavaScript so NO jQuery answers, please.

Having a DB and all will come later, I'm a newbie so I'm using this as a learning tool.

The thing is: I'm trying to make new rows with inputs and two buttons at the end. One for deleting it's own row and the other to "save" the text written on the inputs.

The issue is, when I use `this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();` is works but as this is quite new and not yet fully supported, specially IE i'd like to use the `removeChild` method, but I can't get it right. Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the script code so you can see if there's anything wrong (the delete function is at the end):

```
var $ = function (elem) {
    return document.getElementById(elem);
}
var _ = function (elem) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
}

$("btnAdd").addEventListener("click", Add, true); 

function Add() {
var saveElements = _("btnSave");
var deleteElements = _("btnDelete");

nodeElement = document.createElement("tr");
nodeElement.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+ 
                        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+ 
                        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+ 
                        "<td><button class='btnSave btn blue'>S</button><button class='btnDelete btn red'>D</button></td>";
    $("newElement").appendChild(nodeElement);

    for (var i = 0; i < saveElements.length; i++) {
        saveElements[i].addEventListener("click", Save, true);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < deleteElements.length; i++) {
        deleteElements[i].addEventListener("click", Delete, true);
    }
}
function Save() { }

function Delete() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you attempted to use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)? it's probably just a simple mistake or typo.

Comment: On the last function: `function Delete() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}`

But it seems to not work with the 'this' keyword.

Comment: so, instead of `remove`, you just substituted `removeChild`?

Comment: no, I wrote somethig like `function Delete() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}`

Comment: element.remove() is called without argument to remove the element itself without jumping up to the parentNode... removeChild needs two element refs, one of which is expected to be this.

Comment: You could always just implement `HTMLElement.prototype.remove`. Makes for cleaner code that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an element with removeChild, you must select the elements parent *then* pass the element that you want to remove to `removeChild`.

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
```

this removes `this.parentNode.parentNode`

`this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this)` didn't work because `this` isn't a child of `this.parentNode.parentNode`

Comment: Read the method name. `removeChild` it removes the passed in child from the parent element. Therefore, for the method to work, it needs both the parent, and the child. `parent.removeChild(child)`

Comment: It works and yeah, I get it now. SO thanks a lot ;) That was quick! (I guess easy too... JS is a little complicated as a first language for me I think).